# How can I implement Ord when the comparison depends on data not part of the compared items?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a small struct containing only an `i32`:

```
struct MyStruct {
   value: i32,
}
```

I want to implement `Ord` in order to store `MyStruct` in a `BTreeMap` or any other data structure that requires you to have `Ord` on its elements.

In my case, comparing two instances of `MyStruct` does not depend on the `value`s in them, but asking another data structure (a dictionary), and that data structure is unique for each instance of the `BTreeMap` I will create. So ideally it would look like this:

```
impl Ord for MyStruct {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self, dict: &Dictionary) -> Ordering {
        dict.lookup(self.value).cmp(dict.lookup(other.value))
    }
}
```

However this won't be possible, since an `Ord` implementation only can access two instances of `MyStruct`, nothing more.

One solution would be storing a pointer to the dictionary in `MyStruct` but that's overkill. `MyStruct` is supposed to be a simple wrapper and the pointer would double its size. Another solution is to use a static global, but that's not a good solution either.

In C++ the solution would be easy: Most STL algorithms/data structures let you pass a comparator, where it can be a function object with some state. So I believe Rust would have an idiom to match this somehow, is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Actually, in a 64-bits environment, a pointer would quadruple `MyStruct`'s size from 32 bits to 128 bits (64 pointer, 32 value, 32 padding).

Comment: Do you care about the actual ordering you end up with, or are you simply trying to put the `MyStruct` instances in a map? If it's the latter, it would make much more sense to use a [`HashMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html)

Comment: Oh, well, for the sake of the question let's assume that we need the order. I guess a similar problem would occur with a `BinaryHeap` if you need to pop the min/max value from time to time.

Comment: I made a feature request, I'm running into exactly the same problem and with a small google search, I can clearly see that it is not only me.
 https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/comparator-for-btree-map-set-s/17011

Comment: This may be far too late to be of any use to you @loudandclear, but for future readers of this question it may be helpful to know that my (recently published) [copse](https://crates.io/crates/copse) crate provides an alternative `BTreeMap` that can be instantiated with a custom/runtime-defined comparator.

Answer (score 10):

I remember the debate over whether allowing a custom comparator was worth it or not, and it was decided that this complicated the API a lot when most of the times one could achieve the same effect by using a new (wrapping) type and redefine `PartialOrd` for it.

It was, ultimately, a trade-off: weighing API simplicity versus unusual needs (which are probably summed up as access to external resources).

---

In your specific case, there are two solutions:

- use the API the way it was intended: create a wrapper structure containing both an instance of `MyStruct` and a reference to the dictionary, then define `Ord` on that wrapper and use this as key in the `BTreeMap`
- circumvent the API... somehow

I would personally advise starting with using the API as intended, and measure, before going down the road of trying to circumvent it.

---

[@ker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103681/ker) was kind enough to provide the following illustration of achieving wrapping in comments ([playground version](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=053d6ebaeede239ae4ad&version=stable)):

```
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
   value: i32,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStructAsKey<'a> {
    inner: MyStruct,
    dict: &'a Dictionary,
}

impl<'a> Eq for MyStructAsKey<'a> {}

impl<'a> PartialEq for MyStructAsKey<'a> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.inner == other.inner && self.dict as *const _ as usize == other.dict as *const _ as usize
    }
}

impl<'a> Ord for MyStructAsKey<'a> {
    fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> ::std::cmp::Ordering {
        self.dict.lookup(&self.inner).cmp(&other.dict.lookup(&other.inner))
    }
}

impl<'a> PartialOrd for MyStructAsKey<'a> {
    fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Option<::std::cmp::Ordering> {
        Some(self.dict.lookup(&self.inner).cmp(&other.dict.lookup(&other.inner)))
    }
}

#[derive(Default, Debug)]
struct Dictionary(::std::cell::RefCell<::std::collections::HashMap<i32, u64>>);

impl Dictionary {
    fn ord_key<'a>(&'a self, ms: MyStruct) -> MyStructAsKey<'a> {
        MyStructAsKey {
            inner: ms,
            dict: self,
        }
    }
    fn lookup(&self, key: &MyStruct) -> u64 {
        self.0.borrow()[&key.value]
    }
    fn create(&self, value: u64) -> MyStruct {
        let mut map = self.0.borrow_mut();
        let n = map.len();
        assert!(n as i32 as usize == n);
        let n = n as i32;
        map.insert(n, value);
        MyStruct {
            value: n,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let dict = Dictionary::default();
    let a = dict.create(99);
    let b = dict.create(42);
    let mut set = ::std::collections::BTreeSet::new();
    set.insert(dict.ord_key(a));
    set.insert(dict.ord_key(b));
    println!("{:#?}", set);
    let c = dict.create(1000);
    let d = dict.create(0);
    set.insert(dict.ord_key(c));
    set.insert(dict.ord_key(d));
    println!("{:#?}", set);
}
```

Comment: @ker: I've been trying to toy with creating a second one which would allow per-map dictionary... and to be honest I haven't exactly been wildly successful!

Comment: @ker: I was thinking of rewrapping the `BTreeMap` and then each time a method is invoked switching a thread-local-variable (and restoring its previous value at the end of the invocation) but... I kinda need some `AnyMap` for the thread-local-variable to be able to express it in a generic manner (maybe I should just dump genericity) and lifetimes will force me into using unsafe code, and there's a lot of interface to wrap, ... it's rather painful

Comment: @ker: I have added your example in the answer to avoid it being lost in case comments are cleaned up. Another solution would be for you to provide it as an answer, in which case I would remove it from mine and upvote you :)

Comment: Thanks! I've seen discussions mentioning that creating a new type and implementing Ord would be enough for simulating different comparison methods, so custom comparators aren't necessary. However, it doesn't simulate closures. Did the discussions you saw mention this issue, if they did can you provide a link?

Comment: @loudandclear: to be honest it was more than a year ago (before 1.0) so I have no idea how to find the discussion again. As for closures, I do not remember if (or how) they were discussed. The only interest of closures is closing over an environment, so if you embark the environment within your structures (via a shared pointer, for example) then closures are not necessary any longer... but this does inflate the size of the structures.

Answer (score 9):

Rust (more specifically Rust's libcollections) currently has no comparator-like construct, so using a mutable static is probably your best bet. This is also used within `rustc`, e.g. the string interner is static. With that said, the use case isn't exactly uncommon, so maybe if we petition for it, Rust will get external comparators one day.

Comment: Is there anything in the language specification that prevents the use of them? If a data structure takes a closure as an argument in its constructor and store it, that should be enough. So I guess the problem isn't that "it's not possible", it's just that the standard library isn't designed that way?

Comment: Exactly. You *can* do it, just not with `std::collections` as it is.

Comment: libstd collections can add support for this in a later version by adding defaulted type parameters.

Comment: @bluss: Indeed, much like 1.7 now offers the ability to customize the hash algorithm in hash maps!

Comment: I made a feature request, I'm running into exactly the same problem and with a small google search, I can clearly see that it is not only me.
 https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/comparator-for-btree-map-set-s/17011