# How do I use an external data structure in the comparison function for BinaryHeap?

Tags: rust

I am trying to use a `BinaryHeap` where the `cmp` function requires the use of a `HashMap` external to the two things being compared.

After reading the answer to  [How can I implement Ord when the comparison depends on data not part of the compared items?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35791329/1791872), I tried to do something similar by wrapping the values being compared with a struct also storing a reference to the required data structure:

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Foo {
    x: u8,
}

struct Bar {
    foos: Vec<Foo>,
}

impl<'a> Bar {
    pub fn new(size: u8) -> Bar {
        let mut bar = Bar {
            foos: Vec::with_capacity(size as usize),
        };

        for i in 0..size {
            bar.foos.push(Foo { x: i })
        }

        bar
    }

    pub fn func(&self) {
        #[derive(Eq, PartialEq)]
        struct FooWrapper<'a> {
            foo: &'a Foo,
            val_map: &'a HashMap<&'a Foo, u16>,
        }

        impl<'a> Ord for FooWrapper<'a> {
            fn cmp(&self, other: &FooWrapper) -> Ordering {
                let val_a = self.val_map[self.foo];
                let val_b = other.val_map[other.foo];
                val_b.cmp(&val_a).then_with(|| self.foo.x.cmp(&other.foo.x))
            }
        }

        impl<'a> PartialOrd for FooWrapper<'a> {
            fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &FooWrapper) -> Option<Ordering> {
                Some(self.cmp(other))
            }
        }

        let mut val_map = HashMap::new();
        val_map.insert(&self.foos[0], 5);
        val_map.insert(&self.foos[1], 2);
        val_map.insert(&self.foos[2], 3);

        let mut heap = BinaryHeap::new();
        heap.push(FooWrapper {
            foo: &self.foos[0],
            val_map: &val_map,
        });

        while !heap.is_empty() {
            let _f = heap.pop().unwrap().foo;
            //
            // Some other stuff
            //
            val_map.insert(&self.foos[0], 3);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let bar = Bar::new(3);
    bar.func();
}
```

This results in the error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `val_map` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:64:13
   |
56 |             val_map: &val_map,
   |                      -------- immutable borrow occurs here
...
59 |         while !heap.is_empty() {
   |                ---- immutable borrow later used here
...
64 |             val_map.insert(&self.foos[0], 3);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

It seems that `while !heap.is_empty() {` causes problems, as I don't see this error without that line, but could not find a workaround.

I then tried making the `HashMap` reference stored in my wrapper mutable:

```
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq)]
struct FooWrapper<'a> {
    foo: &'a Foo,
    val_map: &'a mut HashMap<&'a Foo, u16>,
}
```

```
heap.push(FooWrapper {
    foo: &self.foos[0],
    val_map: &mut val_map,
});
```

This results in:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:44:31
   |
44 |                 Some(self.cmp(other))
   |                               ^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected reference `&Bar::func::FooWrapper<'a>`
              found reference `&Bar::func::FooWrapper<'_>`
note: the anonymous lifetime #3 defined on the method body at 43:13...
  --> src/main.rs:43:13
   |
43 | /             fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &FooWrapper) -> Option<Ordering> {
44 | |                 Some(self.cmp(other))
45 | |             }
   | |_____________^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 42:14
  --> src/main.rs:42:14
   |
42 |         impl<'a> PartialOrd for FooWrapper<'a> {
   |              ^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:44:31
   |
44 |                 Some(self.cmp(other))
   |                               ^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected reference `&Bar::func::FooWrapper<'a>`
              found reference `&Bar::func::FooWrapper<'_>`
note: the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 42:14...
  --> src/main.rs:42:14
   |
42 |         impl<'a> PartialOrd for FooWrapper<'a> {
   |              ^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the anonymous lifetime #3 defined on the method body at 43:13
  --> src/main.rs:43:13
   |
43 | /             fn partial_cmp(&self, other: &FooWrapper) -> Option<Ordering> {
44 | |                 Some(self.cmp(other))
45 | |             }
   | |_____________^
```

Is there a way to make this work, or an alternative path?

Comment: Have you read [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/), specifically [the rules of references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references)? You cannot have any other outstanding references when you have a mutable reference.

Comment: I haven't read it in its entirety, but I have read these parts. However, I'm still left with trying to work out how to do this properly given the restrictions.

Comment: This may be far too late to be of any use to you @flau, but for future readers of this question it may be helpful to know that my (recently published) [copse](https://crates.io/crates/copse) crate provides an alternative `BinaryHeap` that can be instantiated with a custom/runtime-defined comparator (or at least it will, once v0.3.0 is released: the currently published versions only provide a `BTreeMap` and `BTreeSet`, but you can use the master branch from [github repo](https://github.com/eggyal/copse) in the interim).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how that could work. IIUC, you change the hash map that defines the order of your items after you have added the items to the heap. But if the order changes, then the heap is no longer a heap until it is reorganized to take into account the new order. I don't know of any general-purpose heap implementation that allows such reorganizing on the fly, so you'd probably need to roll your own.

That being said, and given the reorganizing costs, you're probably better off storing your values in a `Vec` and doing a linear search for the min:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
struct Foo {
    x: u8,
}

struct Bar {
    foos: Vec<Foo>,
}

impl<'a> Bar {
    pub fn new(size: u8) -> Bar {
        let mut bar = Bar {
            foos: Vec::with_capacity(size as usize),
        };

        for i in 0..size {
            bar.foos.push(Foo { x: i })
        }

        bar
    }

    pub fn func(&self) {
        let mut val_map = HashMap::new();
        val_map.insert(&self.foos[0], 5);
        val_map.insert(&self.foos[1], 2);
        val_map.insert(&self.foos[2], 3);

        let mut workset: Vec<_> = self.foos.iter().collect();

        while !workset.is_empty() {
            // Look for the "minimum" item
            let i = workset.iter().skip (1).enumerate().fold (0, |best, (k, x)| {
                if val_map[x] < val_map[workset[best]] { k } else { best }
            });
            let _f = workset.swap_remove (i);
            
            //
            // Some other stuff
            //
            val_map.insert(&self.foos[0], 3);
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let bar = Bar::new(3);
    bar.func();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d0cefa36f99410ba84e8df5cf34c9c85)