# Capturing a local variable in a local function

Tags: rust

I have this maze-like thing with 2 points in it and I want the distance between those points through the maze. To do this I will use A* (unless there is a better algorithm I don't know about), but to use A* I need my `SN` (search node) struct to implement the `Ord` trait. I want to use the Manhattan distance from 1 location to another as heuristic, so I had code like this ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a31e5b5f6e34f8f1dd92db2e3d72cddc)):

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

fn main() {
    let something_i_need_in_cmp = 5;

    struct SN {
        loc: u16,
        step: u16,
    }
    
    impl Ord for SN {
        fn cmp(&self, other: &Self) -> Ordering {
            let tc = self.step + something_i_need_in_cmp;
            let oc = other.step + something_i_need_in_cmp;
            tc.cmp(&oc)
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work because the `to` variable is not captured:

```
error[E0434]: can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item
  --> src/main.rs:13:34
   |
13 |             let tc = self.step + something_i_need_in_cmp;
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: use the `|| { ... }` closure form instead

error[E0434]: can't capture dynamic environment in a fn item
  --> src/main.rs:14:35
   |
14 |             let oc = other.step + something_i_need_in_cmp;
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = help: use the `|| { ... }` closure form instead

error[E0277]: can't compare `SN` with `SN`
   --> src/main.rs:11:10
    |
11  |     impl Ord for SN {
    |          ^^^ no implementation for `SN < SN` and `SN > SN`
    |
    = help: the trait `PartialOrd` is not implemented for `SN`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `SN: Eq` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:11:10
    |
11  |     impl Ord for SN {
    |          ^^^ the trait `Eq` is not implemented for `SN`
```

Is there any way around this?

1. The error hints `` use the `|| { ... }` closure form instead ``, but I don't seem to be able to get this right. Can this help fix it?
2. An answer I found online suggested to add the extra data (the `to` variable in my case) to the struct (here `SN` but for searching like this that would mean that the `to` variable (or a reference to it) is copied a 100 times, which is not efficient.

Comment: @Shepmaster I figured my code fragment was pretty clear, but to answer your question, I use no crates, no Cargo, and only ```std::cmp::Ordering``` for the standard library, of Ord. I have created a Rust playground link with a simplified code: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a31e5b5f6e34f8f1dd92db2e3d72cddc
I also added the exact error from the compiler (and you can see this in the playground too)

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How can I implement Ord when the comparison depends on data not part of the compared items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35786878/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster I saw that post, and it is close to the same question, but I tried the answers there and they did not help me, while NovaDenizen actually helped me with a good answer

Comment: Oh, also @Shepmaster, with the edits you made some parts of the question don't make sense anymore now (like my reference to the 'to' variable), and imo my original question was better then how it is now, but maybe that is just my opinion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're wanting to use a dynamic ordering for the points, but the big problem here is that `Ord` (and all other Rust traits) need to be defined statically, at compile-time.

My suggestion is that instead of using bare `SN` structs in your code, use `SN` structs 'decorated' with a distance, i.e. `(u32, SN)`.  These tuples derive `Ord` so they ought to work in your priority queues, etc.

You still need an `impl Ord for SN` implementation for the `(Distance, SN)` trick to work.  The good news here is that any arbitrary `Ord` definition, including a default one (`#[derive(...)]`) will work.

```
use std::cmp::Ordering;

fn main() {
    let something_i_need_in_cmp = 5;

    #[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Ord, PartialOrd)]
    struct SN {
        loc: u16,
        step: u16,
    }
        
}
```

Comment: I tried this, and it did not work, my guess is that SN still needs ```Ord``` since they are in the tuple, but either way the compiler still complains that SN needs ```Ord```. Also as far as the 'dynamic ordering', I just want to use the priority queue, I would be fine with just assigning 1 weight to a SN (as to make it explicitly not dynamic) but the Rust std priority queue wants me to use ```Ord``` it seems. If the tuples worked like this I would be all happy, but they don't allow SN to not implement ```Ord```

Comment: @KoenduBuf Sorry, I left an important bit out of my answer.  I've edited it.

Comment: Thanks, with that extra bit I'll accept this answer :D