# How to add keys of a HashMap in BinaryHeap by comparing the values of the keys?

Tags: rust

I have a HashMap<&str, i32> that stores the frequency of different words. I have to return the top k most frequent strings. I have done this question before using Java but I was not able to figure out how to do it in rust.

```
//my hashmap 
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
//my priority queue
PriorityQueue<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>pq = new PriorityQueue<>(
            (a,b) -> a.getValue() == b.getValue() ? b.getKey().compareTo(a.getKey()) :a.getValue() - b.getValue()
        );
```

I created a PriorityQueue and passed the comparator that I needed, I am not sure how to to do the same thing in rust.

eg:
Map {
"hello": 2,
"world" : 3,
"program": 1
}

I want the BinaryHeap to look like this:
Heap {"world", "hello", "program"};

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's not possible for the comparison function (`Ord` impl) to refer to data it doesn't contain, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35786878/how-can-i-implement-ord-when-the-comparison-depends-on-data-not-part-of-the-comp). In your case, since you don't want to change the priority of a key after insertion, you can insert a tuple of `(count, T)`. You can wrap the value in `std::cmp::Reverse` to turn the default max-heap into a min-heap.

Here's the code to extract the top 5 most frequent chars from a string using a HashMap to count and then BinaryHeap to extract the top values:

```rust
use std::cmp::Reverse;
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.";

    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    for char in text.chars() {
        *map.entry(char).or_insert(0) += 1;
    }

    let mut heap = BinaryHeap::new();

    for (char, count) in map {
        heap.push(Reverse((count, char)));
        if heap.len() > 5 {
            heap.pop(); // Remove the least frequent.
        }
    }

    dbg!(heap
        .into_sorted_vec()
        .into_iter()
        .map(|Reverse(data)| data)
        .collect::<Vec<_>>());
}
```

Output:

```
[src/main.rs:22] heap.into_sorted_vec().into_iter().map(|Reverse(data)|
            data).collect::<Vec<_>>() = [
    (
        90,
        ' ',
    ),
    (
        59,
        'e',
    ),
    (
        43,
        't',
    ),
    (
        39,
        's',
    ),
    (
        38,
        'n',
    ),
]
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3a406c701a3b6cbfb5126b7aa6732c7d)